# RedirectToRoute("Default") and Redirect(returnUrl) are returning '200' instead of '302'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm trying to use the following code to log users in:

```
$("form").submit(function(event)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus)
        {
            if (XMLHttpRequest.status === 302)
            {
                // if they've successfully logged in, I redirect to their page
                window.location = XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader("Location");
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

with the following code on the server to handle the post:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public  ActionResult LogOn(MyUser user)
{
    if (ValidateLogOn(user.UserName, user.Password))
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
        {
            return Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("Default");
        }
    }
}
```

I thought both 'Redirect' Action Results were supposed to issue 302s but the XMLHttpRequest.status value is always 200. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT: This is what eventually worked**

```
$("form").submit(function(event)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        complete: function(xhr, textStatus)
        {
            var dataType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");

            if (dataType.indexOf("json") > -1)
            {
                window.location = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).returnUrl;
            }

            if (dataType.indexOf("html") > -1)
            {
                $('#main').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    });            
    return false;
});
```

with the following on the server:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult LogOn(MyUser user, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ValidateLogOn(user.UserName, user.Password))
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    else
    {
        user = (MyUser)Session["CurrentUser"];
        if (user.IsPublic)
        {
            return Json(new { returnUrl = Url.RouteUrl("PublicRoute") });
        }
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Json(new { returnUrl = returnUrl.ToLower() });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { returnUrl = Url.RouteUrl("AdminRoute") });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is automatically following the redirect and requesting the redirect page, which is then returning `200`. Run a proxy (like Fiddler or Charles) to see what I mean.

I'd recommend returning a `200` status, but use a JSON object to specify that you want to redirect the user.

Additionally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call/1534662#1534662) recommends using status `278` (apparently an unused status code, which sounds dangerous to me) in this scenario.